# SQLite query: selecting the newest row for each distinct contact

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm working with the Android SQLite db, and I have a table with messages in it. Each message has a `ContactId`. I need to get a list of the newest message associated with each `ContactId`.

My query looks like this so far:

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP_BY ContactId HAVING ( COUNT(ContactId) = 1 ) ORDER_BY MessageTime DESC
```

However when I run the query I get this exception:

```
near "ContactId": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM messages GROUP_BY ContactId HAVING ( COUNT(ContactId) = 1 ) ORDER_BY MessageTime DESC
```

Here's the table definition in case it helps:

```
create table messages (_id integer primary key autoincrement, ContactId text not null, ContactName text not null, ContactNumber text not null, isFrom int not null, Message text not null, MessageTime int not null);
```

Comment: I am using a StringBuilder class because I have the column names in variables, but that's what it outputs.

Comment: I'm confused by the HAVING statement, why are you filtering on a count of 1?  Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: The HAVING statement I took off of an example of using it as a replacement for DISTINCT because that apparently only allows you to select 1 column (or so I understood).

Comment: And no, it still doesn't work if I remove the HAVING statement. So I guess it doesn't like the GROUP_BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** My answer below does not appear to be working as of SQLite 3.7.5, I suggest using the "JOIN" query suggested by Larry.

You are close. What you need to do is sort all the records first, using a subquery table, and then group them. The values that are returned in the result set will be from the last row in each group. So you actually want newer messages to appear at the bottom if you are trying to get the newset message. The "GROUP BY" already ensures you get one row per ContactId.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY MessageTime) GROUP BY ContactId
```

The HAVING clause is not needed. I haven't used it before but according to the docs the HAVING clause will discard whole groups that don't match, but it doesn't sound like you want any groups discarded, you want results from every ContactId.

Also note there is no underscore in "ORDER BY" or "GROUP BY".

Comment: Do you have some documentation that describes this extremely unusual behavior by SQLite?  The only other database I know that allows non-aggregated columns to appear in the SELECT and not the GROUP BY is MySQL, and in that case the column values chosen are random, not "the last ones".  If the behavior you describe is really the documented behavior of SQLite it would be extremely useful.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation seems a bit mum on this behavior. I searched for a while and found nothing explicit. 

In fact the documentation just seems plain wrong when it describes the GROUP BY keyword as followed by an "ordering-term". For example it rejects "ORDER BY MessageTime ASC", even though "MessageTime ASC" seems to be a valid "ordering-term".

Comment: I did check the documentation and it says ". . . it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set, then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row."  So it sounds like the behavior you describe is possibly unreliable and certainly not guaranteed across versions.  Which is a pity because it seems like a genuinely useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to do it.

This query builds a list of the most recent times for each user, then JOINs that back to the message table to get the message information:

```
 SELECT M1.* FROM messages M1 JOIN 
   (SELECT ContactId, MAX(MessageTime) AS MessageTime FROM messages GROUP BY ContactId) M2
   ON M1.ContactID = M2.ContactID AND M1.MessageTime = M2.MessageTime;
```

This query does something slightly different.  It looks at each message and asks if there exists any later message for the same contact.  If not, the row must be the most recent one:

```
 SELECT M1.* FROM messages M1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM M2 
      WHERE M2.ContactID = M1.ContactID AND M2.MessageTime > M1.MessageTime)
```

Comment: The first query (the join query) is has linear performance O(n) whereas the second query (the exists query) has quadratic performance O(n^2) which is a huge difference. The reason for this is that in the join query the each of the two tables in the join is a query and then the join runs on the results. In the exists query, the subquery depends on the main query and thus is re-executed for each row. I highly recommend choosing the join query. Thanks for both these solutions!